# En python ¿Como puedo redondear un dato?

Tags: python

Necesito hacer que el resultado de mi formula "intervalos=+3.3*(cmath.log(numero_de_datos))" se redondea Ejemplo si mi resultado es 7.345213 se redondee a 7 o si es 7.634 se redondee a 8
Tambien saber si me recomienda el uso de esa biblioteca.

muchas gracias

```
import cmath    

Dato_menor=float(input("asigne dato menor "))
Dato_mayor=float(input("asigne dato mayor "))

intervalos=1+3.3*(cmath.log(numero_de_datos))
print(intervalos)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El nombre de la función que buscas es `round` (No necesitas importar ninguna librería para usarla).

```
>>> round(2.4)
2
>>> round(2.5)
2
>>> round(2.6)
3
```

Otras funciones relacionadas que te pueden interesar son `ceil` y `floor` las cuales redondean al entero más cercano hacia arriba y hacia abajo respectivamente.